# IBM Mobilefirst 7.0 - Difference between SAP NetWeaver Gateway and SAP JCo adapters

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jco, netweaver

What is the difference between SAP NetWeaver Gateway and SAP JCo Adapters ?

SAP NetWeaver Gateway Adapter:

> *"IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation applications can communicate with SAP Netweaver Gateway back-end services by using SAP adapters. Using HTTP rest calls and the OData protocol, applications can remotely create, retrieve, update, and delete entities through the adapter.
> No additional middleware required to communicate with SAP system."*

SAP JCo Adapter:

> *"The SAP Java Connector (SAP JCo) is a middleware component that enables the development of SAP-compatible components and applications in Java."*

Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Service Discovery for SAP NetWeaver support enables the ability to codelessly generate MFP Adapters through exploring SAP sources and altering response data from SAP, through their Gateway product.  Gateway is an extra layer of SAP middleware.  For clients that have Gateway as part of their topology, this is a solid tool for generating custom mobile services.

The MFP JCo adapter provides support for writing custom implementation of service creation. This solution requires custom coding, using the JCo APIs, but is available for all SAP installations.

Summary, they are different animals that solve the same problem, in dramatically different way.  Hope this helps.